# Get scrolling direction in a scrollview?

Tags: android

This should be pretty straightforward but it seems that I missed something --- how do you figure out the direction (left/right/up/down) of a scrolling event for a ScrollView?

The first thing that comes to mind is to store getScrollX() and getScrollY(), then compare them in the next call to the onTouchListener. Is that the right way of doing things?

I'm implementing a custom HorizontalScrollView and I need to disable scrolling and page swipes in one direction only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Research is telling me that there is no scroll listener for that case.
You could try your approch.
Another thing I would try is to override [onScrollChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) (which provides the scroll position before) and so creating your own ScrollView

**Update**:
This one workes for me. It scrolls to the right but not to the left.

```
public class CustomScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(int w, int h, int ow, int oh) {
        if (w < ow) {
            scrollTo(ow, h);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No my approach didn't work. ACTION_DOWN wasn't caught. It's related to HorizontalScrollView being a ViewGroup. Trying your approach now. It may be simpler than overriding onInterceptOnTouchEvent and onTouchEvent, as per the ViewGroup docs.

Comment: Did it work? Is that what your are looking for? Please rate if this is the case

Comment: Yeah, I really liked this method. It's short, simple, and it works. It also works with onTouchListener---I'm overriding that to implement a "snapping" scrollview. The other way is to override onInterceptListener and onTouchListener...which is a complicated dance. I was going to post sample code but you beat me to the punch. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
  scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  float y1 = 0;
  float y0 = 0;

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      y0 = motionEvent.getY();
      Log.i("Y", motionEvent.getAction() + " + " + (y0 - y1));
    } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
      y1 = motionEvent.getY();
      if (y0 - y1 > 0) {
        Log.i("Y", motionEvent.getAction() + " + " + (y0 - y1));
      } else if (y0 - y1 < 0) {
        Log.e("Y", motionEvent.getAction() + " - " + (y0 - y1));
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
});
```