# Hide view when scrollViews scrolls down

Tags: android, view, android-scrollview

i have linearLayout and scrollView in my activity. I want to make next: when i scroll down - hide linearLayout and when i scroll up - show it. 
I have read [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490377/get-scrolling-direction-in-a-scrollview) and I try to make lie that, but onScrollChanged called all time when i put my finger on screen, and it is bad solution as i think.

Then i try to make next:

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

Context context;
public void setContext(Context c) {
    this.context = c;
}

public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("myLogs", "Down ");
            hidePanel();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("myLogs", "Up ");
            showPanel();
            break;

    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
}
```

But this woes not worked correct, when i move scroll up - i get Up Up Down ect.

I will be glad for any ideas how to make this

Edited:
I try:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final int threashold = 70;
            if (mLastY - ev.getY() > threashold) {
                Log.v("teste", "moving up");
                mLastY = ev.getY();
            } else if (mLastY - ev.getY() < -threashold) {
                Log.v("teste", "moving down");
                mLastY = ev.getY();
            }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

When i scroll up i got:

```
09-24 20:22:04.568      497-497/khuta.freeturn V/teste﹕ moving down
09-24 20:22:04.668      497-497/khuta.freeturn V/teste﹕ moving up
09-24 20:22:04.688      497-497/khuta.freeturn V/teste﹕ moving up
```

When i scroll down i got:

```
09-24 20:24:44.559      497-497/khuta.freeturn V/teste﹕ moving up
09-24 20:24:44.719      497-497/khuta.freeturn V/teste﹕ moving down
09-24 20:24:44.809      497-497/khuta.freeturn V/teste﹕ moving down
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know how your layout looks like?

Comment: it doesn't metter for this situation.

Comment: If you say so... I don't know what your layout looks like so I can't tell you how to hide a linearlayout that I don't even know if it's inside the scrollview or outside. But if you're going to use onTouchEvent make sure you save your y position on Action_down and on action_move compare and check if you're scrolling up or down.

Comment: i know how to hire a linearlayout, i have problem with getting direction of scroll moving. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the if's do do whatever action you want.

```
switch (ev.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    mLastY = event.getY();
    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    final int threashold = 50;
    if(mLastY-motionEvent.getY()>threashold)
    {
        Log.v("teste","moving up");
        mLastY = motionEvent.getY();
    }else if(mLastY-motionEvent.getY()<-threashold){
        Log.v("teste","moving down");
        mLastY = motionEvent.getY();
    }
}
```

Comment: mLastY should be 0 for first time?

Comment: Yes. And should be defined globaly.

Comment: What is the problem with the code? If you're saying that the first time you scroll it shows incorrect data change the initial value of mLastY to  `Float.MAX_VALUE` and it will work.

Comment: it works first time, but when i scroll to the end of scrollView, and than scroll up again (to move scrollView) i get next  `moving down mLastY= 58.86328125 Y=586.44525` 
 `moving up mLastY= 586.4452514648438 Y=507.8047`
﹕ `moving up mLastY= 507.8046875 Y=417.5883`

Comment: I left my computer but you can do on  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP to reset the valeu of mLastY again. Also on MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN set the mLastY to event.getY()

Comment: The bracers where correct but ok. I've edited and added the whole switch.

Answer (score 1):

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
```

does not mean that the view is scrolling down. How it works is that when you touch your finger first on the screen then MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is fired and when you removed it, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is called. So what you need to do is, start tracking when you start touching to the screen and use that information when you remove your finger.

Take a look [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) to understand when those actions are fired.