# How can I determine the direction of a vertical ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview, direction

How can I determine the direction of a vertical ScrollView?
I need to hide and display another linear layout accoding to scrollview scroll

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7491074/3111870).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method for that. As there isn't a setter for a listener, but just that method, you will have to create your own ScrollView class and override that method and do your thing in your implementation.

Comment: i think it supports only api version 23 and above

Comment: No, it is there since API level 1, just check the provided link

Comment: supports only api version 23 and above

Comment: Where do you get that from? Click the link I proposed, and at right side you'll see 'Added in API level 1'.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ObservableScrollView extends ScrollView {
private static final int DEFAULT_THRESHOLD_DP = 4;

private ScrollDirectionListener scrollDirectionListener;
private int scrollThreshold;

public ObservableScrollView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    scrollThreshold = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DEFAULT_THRESHOLD_DP, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {
    super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldX, oldY);

    if (Math.abs(y - oldY) > scrollThreshold && scrollDirectionListener != null) {
        if (y > oldY) {
            scrollDirectionListener.onScrollUp(Math.abs(y - oldY));
        } else {
            scrollDirectionListener.onScrollDown(Math.abs(y - oldY));
        }
    }
}

public void setScrollThresholdInPx(int px) {
    scrollThreshold = px;
}

public void setScrollThresholdInDp(Context context, float dp) {
    scrollThreshold = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}

public void setOnScrollDirectionListener(ScrollDirectionListener listener) {
    scrollDirectionListener = listener;
}

public interface ScrollDirectionListener {
    void onScrollDown(int pixels);

    void onScrollUp(int pixels);
}}
```

got answer :) use this custom scrollview

```
ScrollView.setOnScrollDirectionListener(new ObservableScrollView.ScrollDirectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollDown(int pixels) {
            contenttool.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollUp(int pixels) {
            contenttool.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly, what I told you -- overriding 'onScrollChanged()' in a custom version of ScrollView.