# How to detect Scroll view Direction in Android

Tags: android, scrollview

Anyone know how to detect ScrollView direction because I have to show and hide ActionBar on scrolling? I can easily detect with help of listview but don't know about ScrollView.

Comment: Can't you aware with `android:scrollbars`? Also _onScrollChanged_ method you can get `X` and `Y` values which indicates horizontal and vertical scrolling direction. Also use _CoordinateLayout_

Comment: Hope this will help. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview)

Comment: see `View#onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)`

Comment: I have tried 
 scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
            }
        });
but when scroll fast then it's not giving proper Y value so my hide/show concept not working properly .

Answer (score 0):

you can extend the `scrollView` because `scrollview` doesnt have such listener. just extend the scrolView and call your callback from the overrided onScrollChanged method.

then in your xml file use your CustomScrollView like this:

```
<my.package.CustomScrollView>xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Comment: Don't [Copy-paste](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490377/get-scrolling-direction-in-a-scrollview)

Comment: Thanks to reply. I have some concern like 
1. Should I need to change HorizontalScrollView  to VerticalScrollView because I have to detect direction vertically(up/down) ?
2. How to use CustomScrollView Class ?

Answer (score -2):

I think what you meant by scroll was detecting which direction,  a swipe has been made .
 Here is an [example](https://vshivam.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/detecting-up-down-left-right-swipe-on-android/)